# lidR - lasnormalize error handling

Tags: interpolation, lidar, las, lidr, normalize

When normalizing a lasCatalog, the processing stops early with the following error:

```
An error occurred when processing the chunk 22. Try to load this chunk with:
 chunk <- readRDS("/tmp/RtmpdcuTUO/chunk22.rds")
 las <- readLAS(chunk)
No ground point found in the point cloud.
```

I understand this to be a problem with the raw point cloud, however might it be fixed by adding a larger buffer (currently using 100m)? If it can't be remedied, then I would like to simply ignore this "bad" chunk and continue to process the remaining chunks. Does lidR support this out of the box? Or do I need to create a custom `catalog_apply()` to catch the error and move on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> however might it be fixed by adding a larger buffer (currently using 100m)?

What is the size of the chunk? How is it possible that you don't have ground points with a 100 m buffer? Are you sure your point cloud is classified? Is it a particularly small chunk at the edge of the dataset? I can't answer without more information.

> If it can't be remedied, then I would like to simply ignore this "bad" chunk and continue to process the remaining chunks. Does lidR support this out of the box?

Yes it does. In this case the chunk will be skipped and will be missing in the new normalized dataset.

```
opt_stop_early(ctg) <- FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for:  `opt_stop_early(ctg) <- FALSE`. That will prove helpful. The chunks are not at the edge of the dataset and are actually quite large.  The bad chunk is classified but doesn't contain "ground" in its set of classes.

Comment: This is weird. You should check the other files. Maybe some of them are poorly classified. The computation may work but the output  may be weak and you won't see it if you don't check it.